# How to write a macro (VBA code) to connect to Oracle PBCS in smart view using Hyperion functions

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently facing issue with connecting to Oracle PBCS server in smart view. I have a VB code which uses 
Hyperion functions to connect to server. When I execute the code, I don't see any error thrown. But the code is not
connecting to Oracle PBCS server. I have included `smartview.bas` file also.

VB code with Hyperion functions:

```
Public Sub ConnectToOraclePBCS()
X = HypConnect("Sheet1", "username", "password", "server-url")
End Sub
```

Can anyone guide me on what is actually missing in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example from the Oracle Smart View Developer's Guide. You may not be using the correct URL as your vtFriendly name parameter.

> **Planning  Example Using a Connection String**
>
> In this example, we connect to the Planning  Vision application, Plan1 database
>
> HypConnect("Sheet1", "UserName", "Password", "http://hostname:9000/HyperionPlanning/ SmartView|servername|Vision|Plan1")

You already have the smartview.bas file setup so no need to declare but below is the syntax fyi.

> **Syntax**
>
> HypConnect (vtSheetName, vtUserName, vtPassword, vtFriendlyName)
>
> ByVal vtSheetName As Variant
>
> ByVal vtUserName As Variant
>
> ByVal vtPassword As Variant
>
> ByVal vtFriendlyName As Variant
>
> **Parameters**
>
> vtSheetName:  The name of worksheet on which to run the function. If vtSheetName is or Null or Empty, the active worksheet is used.
>
> vtUserName:  A valid user name
>
> vtPassword:  The password for this user
>
> vtFriendlyName:  The connection name of the data provider. The friendly name parameter can accept either of the following:
>
> • A connection name created using  HypCreateConnection
>
> • A connection string consisting of a URL, server name, application name, and database name, in the format URL|server|app|db
>
> The URL component of the connection string follows the guidelines in  Private Connection URL Syntax in the  Oracle Smart View for Office User's Guide.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Returns 0 if successful; otherwise, returns the appropriate error code